# How to ensure exclusive grayscale colors in Illustrator document?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grayscale

I'm using Illustrator CS6 to create several black/white figures. Since the printing agency requires "well" prepared figures, I want to ensure that all figures are in grayscale, or in other words, that no black stroke is an RGB or CMYK black, but a grayscale = 100 black :-) Is there a way to achieve this globally and check this within Illustrator? Or do I have to manually select all elements in my Illustrator file? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you could simply only use the Grey swatches in the **Swatch Panel**.

Or you could select art and choose `Edit > Edit Colors > Convert to Greyscale` -- note that this will not alter placed raster images or raster effects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The "Convert to Grayscale" is I was looking for!